# handled checked items in listview and send item numbers via JSON object

Tags: android, json, listview, android-intent

I have list view with text views and a checkbox. With 4 items in listview. I want to send ay of the 4 options checked by user and send the position number via JSON object to server when I go to next screen.

```
{//onCreatemethod
    myItems= new ArrayList<ItemClass>();

    //my items in the list view...
    myItems.add(new ItemClass("op1", "description op1"));
    myItems.add(new ItemClass("op2", "description op2"));
    myItems.add(new ItemClass("op3", "description op3"));
    myItems.add(new ItemClass("op4", "description op4"));

    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myItems);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    String jsonItem1 = "item1";
    String jsonItem2 = "item2"
    String jsonItem3 = "item3"
    String jsonItem4 = "item4"
    String jsonItem5 = "item5"
}  
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    int pos = gameList.getPositionForView(buttonView);
    if(pos!= ListView.INVALID_POSITION){
        ????

    }


this is my JSON object structure,

{
“item1”:"itemname1",
“item2”:"itemname2",
“item3":"itemname3",
“item4”:"itemname4",
"item5":"itemname5",
“1,2,3”:"user checked items" //checked items will be in this line....
}
```

here 1,2,3 are position numbers of user checked options.

hope this description is enough....

thank you in advance....

Comment: What triger the next screen? How you intend to send the data to the server? you have code for this?

Comment: I have a buttoon which will take me to next screen...right now I dont have next activity design but at this activity I want to have al the elements which then I will put in JSON Object. Code needs to be implemented afterwards..for now I just want to have raw data of the selection....

Comment: Use a JSON library such as GSON or Jackson.

Comment: yes I am going to use that before that I have to create last element that is user checked items as shown in the last line of my question description. For that I am looking for help to handle checked Items in listview.